# Replying to comments via email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Please advice gem or decision to add replying to comments via email, like in BaseCamp.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to send your emails with a `Reply-To` email that you can receive. Then, one way to handle those emails is to use ActionMailer: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#receiving-emails

Answer (score 1):

ActionMailer is the keyword.

You can add an ActionMailer like this:

```
ruby script/generate mailer MailerName view1 view2
```

There are some tutorials out there, concerning the ActionMailer.